# $80$ balls in a row. $50$ of them are yellow and $30$ are blue. Prove that there are at least $2$ blue balls with a distance of exactly $3$ or $6$.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

$80$ balls in a row. $50$ of them are yellow and $30$ are blue. Prove that there are at least $2$ blue balls with a distance of exactly $3$ or $6$.

Please provide any hint or direction. Thank you!

Comment: @Arthur I meant exactly, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide the $80$ slots by congruence $\pmod 3$.  We remark that there are $27$ slots of the form $3n+ 1$, $27$ of the form $3n+2$ and $26$ of the form $3n$.  As we have $30$ blue balls to distribute, at least one of those congruence classes contains at least $10$ blue balls.

Suppose we had a counterexample.  Then the gaps between consecutive blue balls in that congruence class would each have to be at least $2$, but we have at least $9$ gaps and $2\times 9+10=28>27$ so this is impossible, and we are done.

Comment: Can you explain the conclusion please?

Comment: @GalushBalush No matter how you place the balls, either the spots labelled with a number divisible by $3$, or those one higher than a number divisible by $3$, or those one lower than a number divisible by $3$ (or several of them) has 10 blue balls, by pigeonhole principle (30 balls, three categories). Pick a category with at least 10 balls. There are at most $27$ spots, and any two blue balls in that category has to have at least two yellow between them. There just isn't enough space in a single category for that.

Comment: Which part is unclear to you?  I've got $10$ objects to put into $27$ slots.  That gives me at least $9$ gaps (ignoring the possible gaps on the ends).  if each gap is at least $2$ then that means at least $9\times 2 =18$ gaps. Adding the $10$ objects, that would need at least $18+10=28$ slots which is too many.  Note:  there was a typo in my post, I had $29$ when I intended $28$.  Doesn't change anything.

Comment: @lulu I’m trying to understand that problem as well. How does requiring that each gap is at least 2, and reaching a contradiction, help us prove that the gap between some 2 balls is exactly 3 or 6? Thank you

Comment: @NoyPerel  Well, gee.  A gap of $0$ would mean the two slots differ by $3$.  A gap of $1$ would mean they differ by $6$. Honestly, this is fairly trivial.

Comment: @lulu oops, of course! Sorry for a moment I thought of at least as at most :)

Comment: @NoyPerel  No worries.